# Permissions on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello everyone I have a confussion here I'm using WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) when I try to use a command like `cat` throws me the next:

```
luismiguells@Lenovo:~/Code$ cat main.c
cat: main.c: Permission denied
```

It's deny me the access but when I use `sudo` it's show me the content of the file, my question is, there's a way I can do this without using `sudo` everytime, by the way I've tried adding my user with `sudo visudo` but nothing happends.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l main.c`? That should display ownership and permission information about the file. Not sure if WSL has any odds there, but can you simply `sudo chown $USER: main.c` to change the ownership of that file to your current user?

Comment: I've frequently run into problems with WSL where newly created files are owned by root and nobody else has read access. You need to use `sudo chmod a+r main.c` if this is your problem.

Comment: @ByteCommander the output of using `ls` is `---------- 1 luismiguells luismiguells 131 Apr 11 13:24 main.c` @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm sure that would work but it would tired if you 1000 files for example.

Comment: So according to that output, you are the owner, but nobody has any rights. This should be fixable with `chmod 644 main.c`. That will make it readable for everyone and writable for the owner only.

Comment: @ByteCommander that works but what happend if I have 1000 files.

Comment: You can use shell globs like `*` for all files in the current directory (might exclude hidden files) or e.g. `*.c` to match all c files in the current directory, for example `chmod 644 *.c`. Or you can use the recursive switch, to apply the action the given directory and all files and subdirectories inside: `chmod -R a+r,u+w ~/Code`. Note that I use `a+r,u+w` to add read permissions for all and write for the user (owner) here, instead of setting it fixed to 644, because directories need to keep their executable bit, and real executables should keep it too.

Comment: Be careful though, if you apply incorrect permissions on some important files, it may break things. The safe rule is to only change permissions of files and folders you created yourself, leaving those of the system alone.

Comment: @ByteCommander  I think the problem is if I create for example a folder call "foo" outside of WSL gives me an error of permission but if I create a folder inside WSL dosen't give me that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix you can use a find 
find all files with permission 0 and set it to rw-r--r--

`find -perm 0 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

find all directories with permission 0 and set it to rwxr-xr-x

`find -perm 0 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`